Piping a WritableStream through a TransformStream
I am trying to encode/decode messages being sent through the Web Serial API, although I would like the same code to work with other types of ReadableStream / WritableStream.
I have implemented a JavaScript web stream encoder and decoder by subclassing TransformStream. I am successfully reading a stream through the decoder using stream.pipeThrough(decoder) and getting a decoded Uint8Array buffer out of the new ReadableStream.
But I can't work out how to do the same thing in reverse; applying my TransformStream  encoder to a WritableStream, as there is nothing like writableStream.pipeThrough().
My current work around is encode the buffers before writing them to the WritableStream instance.

A writable stream is always at the end of a transform chain, it is the one that finally consumes the stream, so the concept of “piping a writable stream” does not make much sense. What you probably want is piping your encoder into the writable stream, not the other way round.
I don’t have any experience with the Web Serial API, but what I assume is that you want to convert data that you read from SerialPort.readable to your own custom data model and to convert your own custom data model to data that you write to SerialPort.writable. Your approach to subclass TransformStream to create an encoder/decoder sounds good.
To decode the data, you would use port.readable.pipeThrough(new MyDecoder()) and consume the stream it returns, as you have already figured out.
To encode the data, you would pipe your encoder into the writable stream of the port. Either you already have a ReadableStream of your objects: stream.pipeThrough(new MyEncoder()).pipeTo(port.writable). Or you manually write objects to your encoder:
const encoder = new MyEncoder();
encoder.readable.pipeTo(port.writable);
const writer = encoder.writable.getWriter();
await writer.write(object1);
await writer.write(object2);

By using await on writer.write(), you enable back pressure, meaning that your code pauses until the object has been consumed by the port.
